# Laravel7: Running integrations tests end in failure, NOT Found

Tags: php, docker, containers, integration-testing, laravel-7

I am upgrading my `Laravel` app form `L6` to `L7` and when I try to run integration tests, it ends in failure. So here is my setup code:

```
protected function runCommand($command, array $arguments = [], OutputInterface $output = null)
    {
        $process = new Process([$command]);
        $process->setTimeout(120);
        $process->run();

        if ($process->isSuccessful()) {
            \Log::debug('successfully');
        } else {
            \Log::debug('NOT', [$process->getIncrementalErrorOutput()]);
        }
    }
```

Now as you can see, this method is running some commands and when the commnds run, these are the errors I get:

```
[2023-12-05 07:17:31] testing.DEBUG: NOT ["sh: 1: exec: mysql -hdb -uroot -psecret -e \"drop schema if exists phirater_tst; create schema phirater_tst default charset utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci\": not found\n"] 
[2023-12-05 07:17:31] testing.DEBUG: NOT ["sh: 1: exec: ./artisan migrate --database=mysql_testing: not found\n"] 
[2023-12-05 07:17:31] testing.DEBUG: NOT ["sh: 1: exec: mysqldump -hdb -uroot -ppass --add-drop-table phirater_tst > /tmp/e1440949b437f065addb21be548316b4: not found\n"] 
[2023-12-05 07:17:31] testing.DEBUG: NOT ["sh: 1: exec: mysql -hdb -uroot -ppass phirater_tst < /tmp/e1440949b437f065addb21be548316b4: not found\n"]
```

I am on `PHP 7.4` with `L7` running in a `docker container`. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

If I run these commands directly inside the container, these work fine.

Comment: What is this `Process` class? The `Process` facade has only appeared in Laravel 10, I think.